# Image dimension resize and rotate by 90 degree using canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var width = 0;
      var height = 0;
      var diagonal = 0;
      var image = new Image();
      image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      image.src = `source url`;
      image.onload = () => {
        width = image.naturalHeight;
        height = image.naturalWidth;
        diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2));
        ctx.canvas.height = diagonal;
        ctx.canvas.width = diagonal;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(diagonal / 2, diagonal / 2);
        ctx.rotate((0 * Math.PI) / 180);
        ctx.drawImage(image, -width / 2, -height / 2);
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(diagonal / 2, diagonal / 2);
        ctx.rotate((90 * Math.PI) / 180);
        ctx.save();
        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.width = image.width;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.restore();
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
      };
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I have an image of dimensions 1200x900. I want to rotate it by 90 degrees in clockwise and after rotation change its dimension again to 1200*900. How can I do this using canvas of HTML5.
[image: Source image]

I am attaching image here.
[image: Destination image]

I want the destination image to be of size 1200x900. Please let me know, how to do this.

Comment: What you're asking is simply not possible - at least not without distorting the image. If your source image is 1200x900 and you rotate it by 90° it's new dimension will be 900x1200. So to make it 1200x900 afterwards we would have to scale it by a factor of 1,33 horizontally and 0,75 vertically. Maybe there's an error in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere where you calculate the ratio between height & width...
We calculate that and use it in our `drawImage` to reduce the size.

...see sample below:
<sub>I keep the canvas size to the original image to show it in the background</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
  canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
  
  // original image
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);  
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill()
  
  // rotated image
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
  let ratio = canvas.height/canvas.width
  ctx.drawImage(image, -canvas.height / 2, -canvas.width / 2, canvas.width/ratio, canvas.width);
  ctx.restore();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I was not sure what your diagonal calculation was needed for, so I just removed that and anything else not relevant... in future questions if you can explain your logic we can better respond to what/where your approach is going wrong

---

You can use same logic for other similar transformation...
here is another code sample:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.height = canvas.width = Math.max(image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
  
  // original image
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);  
  ctx.rect(0, 0, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
  ctx.fill()
  
  // rotated image
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.translate(image.naturalHeight / 2, image.naturalWidth / 2);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.drawImage(image, -image.naturalWidth / 2, -image.naturalHeight / 2);
  ctx.restore();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```